# What did Jinbe lose in Charlotte's roulette?

Tags: one-piece

I'm a bit lost in Jinbe's status and what happened with him and Big Mom.
In chapter 830, he confronts Big Mom and announces that he is planning on leaving her alliance. In return, she demands that he as well has to lose something valuable as well, and what will it be is decided by the roulette game.

However then in chapter 835, there is a report in the newspaper saying he backed out, which would imply that he has withdrawn his request to leave Big Mom's crew. This is very unlikely considering his portrayal, so I assume this was some kind of false report because later on he also admits to Luffy that his alliance with Big Mom is over. However, I don't know what is the reason for such a false report in the first place, it makes no sense to me and I have also read some theories which are suggesting that he did not lose anything at all which is even weirder, why would Big Mom let him just go that easily?

The only plausible explanation to me is that he has spun the wheel and he lost a bit of his lifespan (or I have missed some important detail in the story).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in chapter 834 afterward, Jinbe didn't go through with the roulette because it is set up in a way that somebody who does it will probably lose his life and that wasn't what he wanted because of his pledge to Luffy.

So he just went for the normal thing somebody would do and he betrayed her in chapter 851 by freeing Luffy from the prison and escaping together with them from Big Mom.

Comment: Yeah in the he really did withdraw.... i did not consider the fact that the roulette could be rigged

Comment: Well if it's rigged it's quite understandable that you would withdraw

Comment: yeah but as i said, initially that idea did not cross my mind. Even without that part the "prizes" were pretty good

Answer (score 1):

I think he lost something like a bit of his lifespan or he has withdrawn his request to leave the crew.

However, we will surely find it out in the next chapters.

Comment: Yeah that is what i assume but some people are saying he backtracked and lost nothing, and given the context that makes no sense to me so i was wondering if i missed anything.

Comment: I don't think you missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Jinbe didn't lose anything.

In the manga, he went through the game, but Charlotte's fruit can't activate on people who don't fear her. Jinbe never feared her and so she couldn't take anything away from him.

Comment: Yeah, we know that now but i have asked the question before it was explained :P

Answer (score 0):

He originally backed down, but later revealed that he didn't spin it in fear for himself but the spinner's crew always suffers from his choice and he didn't want that.

Answer (score 0):

For people who are confuse, the thing he will lose is the life of his friends and comrades, he stated not only his life will be taken away but also his friends life span too, thats why he told sun pirates to leave now

Comment: Hi @uber, welcome to Anime & Manga. Please take our [tour]! Your answer can be improved by adding sources for your claims (for instance, mentioning the manga chapter or anime episode is a start). You can also address how your answer adds or improves upon the existing answers, which already provide a fair amount of information.